# Let K/F be a finite extension, given a polynomial in K[x] find another so that their product is in F[x]

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K$ be a finite extension of a field $F$, and let $f(x)$ be in $K[x]$. Prove that there is a nonzero polynomial $g(x)$ in $K[x]$ such that $f(x)g(x)$ is in $F[x]$.

Should I do this by induction on the degree of $f(x)$?

Obviously if $n=0$, then $g(x)=1/f(x)$

Let $f(x) = a_nx^n+...a_1x+a_0$       then I know that there exists a h(x) so that $(f(x)-a_nx^n)h(x)$      is in $F[x]$. I want now to find a $g(x)=h(x)+i(x)$ so that $f(x)g(x)$ is in $F[x]$. Thus I need to find an $i(x)$ so that $a_nx^nh(x)+i(x)f(x)$ is in $F[x]$. I feel like this is wrong because I have no control over the degrees of $h(x)$.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this homework?  Hint: focus on the case of irreducible $f(x)$ in $K[x]$ and think about minimal polynomials of the same number algebraic over different fields.

Comment: I removed the tag ring-theory ; I believe it is unappropriate.

Comment: @KCd Yes it is. I updated the tags.

Comment: @Steven-Owen : I posted a solution of a slightly general version using field theory only . If you may take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that the extension is Galois. By assumption, there are only finitely many automorphisms of $K$ that fix $F$. The polynomial
$$
\omega(x) = \prod_{\sigma \in \mathrm{Aut}(K/F)} \sigma(f(x))
$$
is a polynomial such that $f(x) \, | \, \omega(x)$ and $\omega$ is fixed by every automorphism of $K/F$, because $\mathrm{Aut}(K/F)$ is a group, so that when one tries to apply an automorphism on $\omega(x)$, the conjugate factors get permuted... hence all the coefficients of $\omega$ lie in the fixed field $F$. You can choose $g(x) = \omega(x) / f(x)$.

Hope that helps,

Comment: I worked out the case where the extension is Galois. Can you work out the other cases?

Comment: Hello Patrick,

Thanks so much for the help. Just to make sure when you say $\sigma(f(x))$ does this act like $\sigma(a_nx^n \ldots a_1x+a_0)=\sigma(a_n)x^n \ldots \sigma(a_1)x+\sigma(a_0)$?

Comment: @jake : Yes, exactly. Automorphisms go through addition/multiplication, so you just apply those rules to apply the automorphisms to $f(x)$. Although it's true that a priori $\sigma : K \to K$, my writing suggests that you can naturally extend this function to $\sigma : K[x] \to K[x]$ by letting $\sigma(x) = x$. When I write $\sigma(f(x))$ I suppose you understand this natural way of extending $\sigma$.

Comment: Awesome. So in the case where the extension is finite but not Galois, I don't want to just consider some Galois extension G/F that has K as an intermediate field and proceed by the same method because then I would not be guaranteed that $w(x)/f(x)$ is in $K[x]$.

Also, I don't think you need the assumption that the extension is Galois to know there are only finitely many automorphisms of K that fix F. This comes just from knowing that K/F is a finite extension and it must be contained in some larger extension that is Galois.

Comment: Yes, but then again you wanted a suggestion and I gave you one. Perhaps you can work the rest out by yourself or wait for someone else to work it out for you, because my Galois theory is rusty ; I gave you my thoughts about this question in $5$ minutes but didn't think it through very much.

Comment: I think the place where you used the Galois property was in knowing that $w(x)$ is in $F[x]$ because it is fixed by group, this is not something that is true in general for galois groups of non-Galois extensions, right?

Comment: I apologize for coming off mean, I am incredibly grateful. I just wanted to ensure that I understood your proof. Sorry!

Comment: @jake : Don't need to be sorry, your questions were fine and I didn't feel overwhelmed or bothered or anything like that. Feel free to keep asking questions ; although at the moment it is better if you continue asking questions in chat if you have to.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2812/discussion-between-jake-and-patrick-da-silva)

Comment: @jake: Are you *sure* you aren't guaranteed that $w(x)/f(x)$ is in $K(x)$ when $w(x)$ and $f(x)$ are?

Answer (score 4):

It becomes easy if you know about integrality over rings. (Here and in the following, "ring" always means "commutative ring with $1$".)

Since $K$ is a finite extension of $F$, we see that $k\in K$ is integral over $F$ for every $k\in K$. Thus, $k\in K\left[x\right]$ is integral over $F\left[x\right]$ for every $k\in K$. Hence, $kx^i\in K\left[x\right]$ is integral over $F\left[x\right]$ for every $k\in K$ and $i\in\mathbb N$ (since $k$ and $x^i$ are both integral over $F\left[x\right]$, and the product of two integral elements is integral). Hence, $f\left(x\right) \in K\left[x\right]$ is integral over $F\left[x\right]$ (since $f\left(x\right)$ is a sum of elements of the form $kx^i$ for $k\in K$ and $i\in\mathbb N$, and since the sum of integral elements is integral). Now, all we need to prove is the following fact:

**(1)** If $ A\subseteq B$ is a ring extension, and $ u\in B$ is integral over $ A$, then there exists a nonzero $ v\in B$ such that $ uv\in A$.

**Proof of (1).** Let $ n$ be the smallest positive integer such that there exists a monic polynomial $ P\in A\left[Y\right]$ of degree $ n$ satisfying $ P\left(u\right)  =  0$. (Such an $n$ exists since $u$ is integral over $A$.) Write the polynomial $P$ in the form $ P\left(Y\right)  =  \sum\limits_{i  =  0}^{n  -  1}a_iY^i  +  Y^n$ with all $a_i$ lying in $A$. Then, set $ v  =  \sum\limits_{i  =  1}^{n  -  1}a_iu^{i  -  1}  +  u^{n  -  1}$. Then, $uv = \sum\limits_{i  =  1}^{n  -  1}a_iu^{i}  +  u^{n} = \underbrace{\sum\limits_{i  =  0}^{n  -  1}a_iu^{i}  +  u^{n}}_{ = P\left(u\right) =0} - a_0 = - a_0 \in A$. Also, $ v\neq 0$ follows from the minimality of $ n$. Thus, **(1)** is proven.

[I have copied some of this from [one of my AoPS posts](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=1581477#p1581477).]

Comment: I removed the tag ring-theory, because I believe it was inappropriate. Yet your argument uses integrality over rings, which is something usually one does not cover when beginning Galois theory (or maybe I am judging, but I have faith in what I'm saying). Do you think you can do a purely field/Galois theory proof by inspiring yourself from your integrality argument?

Comment: In my opinion, the fact that my proof does not depend on Galois theory and fields is more of a feature than a bug; the focus on fields is antiquated and precludes one from exploiting the flexibility of rings. (Natural and useful constructions such as direct sums, quotients, polynomial rings, tensor products etc. of rings are not possible with fields.)

Comment: This is exactly why I had put the ring theory tag on there as well. My course begins with rings and it seemed as though this problem could be solved using those methods, and here we have it. Thanks Darij!

Comment: I wish I could upvote this  amazingly elegant and perfectly written answer more: congratulations, Darij!

Answer (score 1):

A proof using field theory and assuming only that $K/F$ is an algebraic extension .

Let $K^a$ be an algebraic closure of $K$ , $f(x)\in K[x]$ splits in $K^a[x]$ as $f(x)=(x-a_1)...(x-a_n)$

where $a_1,..,a_n \in K^a$ ($a_i$'s are not necessarily distinct) . Each $a_i$ is

algebraic over $K$ and $K$ is algebraic over $F$ , so each $a_i$ is algebraic over $F$ ; let $g_{a_i}(x)=Irr(a_i , F)$

be the irreducible polynomial of $a_i$ over $F$ . Then $h(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n g_{a_i}(x) \in F[x]$ is a non-zero

polynomial . Moreover , $x-a_i|g_{a_i}(x)$ in $K^a[x]$ , so $f(x)|h(x)$ in $K^a[x]$ . Now $f(x),h(x) \in K[x]$ ;

by division algorithm , $\exists q(x) , r(x)\in K[x]$ such that $h(x)=f(x)q(x)+r(x)$ where either

$r(x)=0$ or $\deg r(x)< \deg f(x)$ . But then , as $f(x),h(x),q(x),r(x) \in K^a[x]$ and $f(x)|h(x)$ in

$K^a[x]$ , so $f(x)|r(x)$ in $K^a[x]$ , then $\deg r(x) <\deg f(x)$ is not possible , hence $r(x)=0$ . Hence

$h(x)=f(x)q(x)$ , where $h(x) \in F[x]$ is a non-zero polynomial and $f(x) , q(x) \in K[x]$ ,

which is what we wanted to prove .